# Where do I set TCP_NODELAY in this C++ TCP Client?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

Where do I set `TCP_NODELAY` in this C++ TCP Client?

```
    // Client socket descriptor which is just integer number used to access a socket
    int sock_descriptor;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    // Structure from netdb.h file used for determining host name from local host's ip address
    struct hostent *server;

    // Create socket of domain - Internet (IP) address, type - Stream based (TCP) and protocol unspecified
    // since it is only useful when underlying stack allows more than one protocol and we are choosing one.
    // 0 means choose the default protocol.
    sock_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock_descriptor < 0)
        printf("Failed creating socket\n");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    server = gethostbyname(host);

    if (server == NULL) {
        printf("Failed finding server name\n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    memcpy((char *) &(serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr), (char *) (server->h_addr), server->h_length);

    // 16 bit port number on which server listens
    // The function htons (host to network short) ensures that an integer is
    // interpreted correctly (whether little endian or big endian) even if client and
    // server have different architectures
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (connect(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to connect to server\n");
        return -1;
    } else
        printf("Connected successfully - Please enter string\n");
```

Comment: Call setsocketopt any time after you get the socket descriptor. Due diligence requires me to ask why you want to turn Nagel off. Nagel is your friend.

Comment: @user4581301 Because comms are from a vm to its host.

Comment: Still going to have to eat all of the extra packet overhead. If you are aiming for low latency, may I recommend UDP, possibly with a lightweight handshake to confirm receipt, instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP_NODELAY is option given to setsockopt system call:

```
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int yes = 1;
int result = setsockopt(sock,
                        IPPROTO_TCP,
                        TCP_NODELAY,
                        (char *) &yes, 
                        sizeof(int));    // 1 - on, 0 - off
 if (result < 0)
      // handle the error
```

This is to set Nagle buffering off. You should turn this option on only if you really know what you are doing.

Comment: `TCP_NODELAY` is not found.  What library should I be importing?

Comment: got it.  `#include <netinet/tcp.h>`